# Markup extension breaks on upgrading from Extended WPF Toolkit to 2.0

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, markup-extensions

This is a problem I ran into after upgrading, for unrelated reasons, from version 1.9.0 to 2.0.0 of the Extended WPF toolkit.  Despite some time spent bashing my head against it, I'm still not sure whether the problem is with it, with my code, or just something no-one thought of at the time.

I had, previously, a PropertyGrid style that set up type-based custom editors for several different data types, using the TargetType property of the EditorDefinition.  This obviously didn't work under 2.0.0, inasmuch as EditorDefinition is obsoleted, so, per the warning messages given, I rewrote the style using EditorTemplateDefinition and TargetProperties, thus:

https://gist.github.com/cerebrate/6695088

Here's the problem.  If I comment out the upper two EditorTemplateDefinitions, those using the {arkane:Nullable} markup extension, the remainder of the style (the two definitions using the {x:Type} markup extension) works.  If I leave them in, as soon as the window containing the property grid is shown, the application crashes with a XamlParseException, could not convert System.RuntimeType to IList.

The {arkane:Nullable} is a simple but pretty standard - or at least commonly seen - extension to TypeExtension to provide the ability to use nullable types in XAML:

https://gist.github.com/cerebrate/6695095

But more to the point, it's a simple subclass of TypeExtension and worked just fine when applied to TargetType in EditorDefinition, and hasn't been changed since.

Any ideas as to what part of the change broke this and how to fix it, on either end?

Or, alternatively, is there any way to associate a custom editor for the Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid with a nullable type without using such a markup extension?

Comment: What you have encountered is not the only problem. In 2.0.0 property grid, auto-generate properties for a DateTime property does not work. I have to roll back to 1.9.0.

Comment: I ended up temporarily working around my problem by adding the template definitions in code every time, rather than having them in the resources.  Which is a hideous kludge, but does fix the problem.